# Carrying user session from subdomain to main domain codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a domain call `member.mydomain.com` that use for member login and member control panel,
but I want all the session variable on member.mydomain.com can be access on `www.mydomain.com`. I’m using CodeIgniter, I'm set on `config.php`

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "member.mydomain.com";
```

Also on my main domain to

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "member.mydomain.com";
```

That’s not work. even I’m change to `.mydomain.com`, everytime after I’m login and success than I’m going to main domain the session not shown, when I’m back to member the session is gone after I’m refresh the page.

So what the right way to carry over session from sub domain to main domain?

Comment: You should store session to database.

Comment: @LLL still not working. I'm creating table for ci_session and set sess_use_database to true and still not working.